# CascadeType.MERGE - Avoiding IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity are being merged

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade, illegalstateexception

Say I have two entities, `Book` and `Person`. `Book` contains two `Person` fields, one for the Author and one for the Editor. The relationships are `@ManyToOne` on the `Book` side:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
public class Book {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Person author;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Person editor;
    ...
}

@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
public class Person {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Book authored;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "editor", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Book edited;
    ...
}
```

If I receive an XML representation of a detached `Book`, containing a detached `Person` as a sub-entity, I can persist the book using a spring `JpaRepository` and the person is also persisted.

However, in the case that one `Person` both authors and edits the same `Book`;

```
Book: The Very Hungry Caterpillar
    Author: Eric Carle
    Editor: Eric Carle
```

I would get the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [my.project.Person#1] are being merged. Detached: [my.project.Person@4729256a]; Detached: [my.project.Person@56ed25db]
```

I can 'solve' this by removing `CascadeType.PERSIST` from the relationships. However this would result in an `EntityNotFoundException`:

```
EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find my.project.Person with id 759.
```

This can be furthered by changing the JPA annotation argument `CascadeType.MERGE` to a Hibernate annotation:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
private Person author;
...
```

I believe this will allow Hibernate to effectively choose whether to merge or persist a sub-entity, based on its persistence state. This will however not result in the duplicate `Person` objects being persisted. I will then get a JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException:

```
JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find my.project.Person 759.
```

This can be worked around by adding another annotation:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Person author;
...
```

However this does not solve the issue, as the `Person` object will still need to be persisted manually.

Is it at all possible to persist two representations of a detached sub-entity using JPA?

**Edit:** hashCode() and equals() are implemented, and both `Person` objects evaluate to be equal.

Comment: Have you assigned both person objects the same ID, and implemented both `Person.equals()` and `Person.hashCode()`?

Comment: Sorry, yes they are identical objects (this is garaunteed from the source of the XML), and I have implemented hashCode() and equals() using project lombok's `@EqualsAndHashCode' annotation.

Comment: were you able to find the solution to your problem?